# Print format for 2D arrays with text

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, printf

I've been trying to make a program that will just write 2D arrays with the following text through print format. The output I am expecting supposedly should look like this, don't mind the bold points they are meant for new line:

```
Name : Florence
Tel. # : 735-1234
Address: Chicago
*
Name : Joyce
Tel. # : 983-3333
Address: Evanston
*
Name : Becca
Tel. # : 456-3322
Address: Oak Park
```

This is my code so far:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] entry = {
            {"Florence", "735-1234", "Chicago"},
            {"Joyce", "983-3333", "Evanston"},
            {"Becca", "456-3322", "Oak Park"}};

    for (int i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < entry[i].length; q++) {
            System.out.printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s",
                    "Name   :   " + entry[i][q],
                    "Tel. # :   " + entry[i][q],
                    "Address:   " + entry[i][q]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But my output only shows this:

```
*
Name   :   Florence
Tel. # :   Florence
Address:   Florence
Name   :   735-1234
Tel. # :   735-1234
Address:   735-1234
Name   :   Chicago
Tel. # :   Chicago
Address:   Chicago
*
Name   :   Joyce
Tel. # :   Joyce
Address:   Joyce
Name   :   983-3333
Tel. # :   983-3333
Address:   983-3333
Name   :   Evanston
Tel. # :   Evanston
Address:   Evanston
*
Name   :   Becca
Tel. # :   Becca
Address:   Becca
Name   :   456-3322
Tel. # :   456-3322
Address:   456-3322
Name   :   Oak Park
Tel. # :   Oak Park
Address:   Oak Park
```

Any tip or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need the inner loop, just one loop to iterate over the entries; the data you want to print will then be `entry[i][0]`, `entry[i][1]`, and `entry[i][2`.

Comment: _Any tip or advice will be greatly appreciated_ Learn to use a debugger. If you are using an IDE, like [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) then it should include a debugger.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Hi! Yup basically the second bracket is fixed and the for loop is only used to iterate the first bracket. Thank you so much for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

though most of the code you've written is correct, you just don't need 2nd for loop. Below is why
**when q=0, your code is printing**
Name = entry[0][0]
Tel. #= entry[0][0]
Address = entry[0][0]
**when q=1, your code is printing**
Name = entry[0][1]
Tel. #= entry[0][1]
Address = entry[0][1]
**when q=2, your code is printing**
Name = entry[0][2]
Tel. #= entry[0][2]
Address = entry[0][2]

I think, here you got fair idea on what happens next. Above process goes on till i<3 and q<3. 
This type of printing you can avoid just by excluding 2nd for loop in your code and add something like below

```
for ( int i= 0; i < entry.length; i++){
               System.out.printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s", "Name   :   " + entry[i][0], "Tel. # :   " +entry[i][1], "Address:   " + entry[i][2]);
           System.out.println();
       }
```

when above code snippet runs, you can see the expected output as you mentioned above.
**when i=0, your code is printing**
Name = entry[0][0]
Tel. #= entry[0][1]
Address = entry[0][2]
Next 2 steps you can follow I guess.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hello! Just woke up class was suspended today so I can easily catch up. Ohh yup that makes a lot of sense. Basically the second bracket is already fixed and the iteration of i will just follow along through the for-loop. Thank you so much for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use `Arrays.deepToString(entry)`.

However that comes at the cost that you cannot specify anything between the array elements. If your priority is to display the additional Text, I suggest the other answer already present. If your priority is a well working, understandable and fast-to-code solution, then my suggestion works better.

Comment: Hello! Oh I believe this meant for a more shorter a faster program to display the assigned work for me. Will still tinker with this method tho!! Thank you so much! :)